# reportviewer control issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to learn how to use reportviewer.

Under the toolbox and under Data Tab, I learned there should be reportviewer control which I can drag into aspx page designer. But I can not find reportviewer control. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to not have install it.

But first search to be sure...
Start from an aspx page on design form, then on the tool box, in my computer there is a Reporting tab.

Now if you do not see it go to any tab on toolbox, rightclick on it, and find by clicking on "chose items" and add the

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
```

and you get the Reporting

If you do not find when you search it, get it here and install it.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=35F23B3C-3B3F-4377-9AE1-26321F99FDF0&displaylang=en